# Greedy regex finding latest brace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse some variable definition to extract documentation automatically, but I'm having trouble skipping some `}` which potentially appear in the default value.

Here's a sample...

```
variable "a" {
  type = string
  description = "A desc"
  default = ""
}

variable "b" {
  type = map()
  description = "B desc"
  default = {}
}

variable "c" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "C desc"
  default = []
}
```

And the regex I'm using

```
variable.\"(?<name>\w+)\"(.*?)description.=."(?<desc>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"(.*?)}
```

with a replace of

```
'* `${name}`: ${desc}
```

This gives the output

```
* `a`: A desc

* `b`: B desc
}

* `c`: C Desc
```

I need the regex to be in single line mode and non-greedy so it stays within each variable definition, but then I can't seem to stop it matching on the first trailing `}` it finds. What would be good is if could match `^}` - but again we are in single line mode so it doesn't apply.

Comment: Try ending it with the lookahead `(?=variable|$)` instead of `}` so it will stop before the next "variable" or the end of file.  Although you'll need to add the blank lines back in your replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work for your dataset:

```
variable.\"(?<name>\w+)\"(.*?)description.=."(?<desc>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"(.*?)(?=[^}]+?variable|$)
```

[Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z5s1UZ/1)

Here I replaced `}` at the end with `(?=[^}]+?variable|$)`. This should ensure that the last capturing group will keep consuming characters until there are no more closing braces before the next `variable` (or the end of the input).

Answer (score 1):

You can match the variable and the description values and match all lines in between that do not start with `}` using a negative lookahead.

```
variable\s*"(?<name>\w+)"\s*{(?:(?!\r?\n}|\bdescription\b).)*description\s*=\s*"(?<desc>[^"]*(?:\\.[^"]*)*)"(?:(?!\r?\n}).)*\r?\n}
```

**Explanation**

- `variable\s*"` Match variable and then `"`
- `(?<name>\w+)` Group `name`, match 1+ word chars
- `"\s*{` Match optional whitespace chars and `{`
- `(?:(?!\r?\n}|\bdescription\b).)*` Match any char using the dot (Single line mode) when what is directly to the right is not a newline and `}` or description
- `description\s*=\s*"` match `description="` with optional whitespace chars around the `=` and then `"`
- `(?<desc>[^"]*(?:\\.[^"]*)*)` Named group `desc` to capture the description
- `"` Match the closing `"`
- `(?:(?!\r?\n}).)*` Match any char (Using the Single line mode) when what is directly to the right is not a newline and `}`
- `\r?\n}` Match a newline and `}`

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=variable%5cs*%22%28%3f%3cname%3e%5cw%2b%29%22%5cs*%7b%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cr%3f%5cn%7d%7c%5cbdescription%5cb%29.%29*description%5cs*%3d%5cs*%22%28%3f%3cdesc%3e%5b%5e%22%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5d*%29*%29%22%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cr%3f%5cn%7d%29.%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%7d&i=variable+%22a%22+%7b%0d%0a++type+%3d+string%0d%0a++description+%3d+%22A+desc%22%0d%0a++default+%3d+%22%22%0d%0a%7d%0d%0a%0d%0avariable+%22b%22+%7b%0d%0a++type+%3d+map%28%29%0d%0a++description+%3d+%22B+desc%22%0d%0a++default+%3d+%7b%7d%0d%0a%7d%0d%0a%0d%0avariable+%22c%22+%7b%0d%0a++type+%3d+list%28string%29%0d%0a++description+%3d+%22C+desc%22%0d%0a++default+%3d+%5b%5d%0d%0a%7d&r=%27*+%60%24%7bname%7d%60%3a+%24%7bdesc%7d&o=s)

[image]

---

It's quite verbose, but a bit more optimized pattern might be

```
variable\s*"(?<name>\w+)"\s*{[^}d]*(?>}(?<!\r?\n.)[^}]*|(?!\bdescription\s*=\s*"[^"]*")d[^d]*)*\bdescription\s*=\s*"(?<desc>[^"]*(?:\\.[^"]*)*)"[^}]*(?:}(?<!\r?\n.)[^}]*)*\r?\n}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qRnE5i/1)